# Get selected value JList or List in Java Swing, stuck with getElementAt() of ListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, list.selectedvalue

i am using Swing List control to bind data, I (must) use a class to make the model

```
public class SubjectListModel extends AbstractListModel<String> {

public ArrayList<Subject> listSubjects;

public SubjectListModel(ArrayList<Subject> listSubjects) {
    this.listSubjects = listSubjects;
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return listSubjects.size();
}

@Override
public String getElementAt(int index) {
    return listSubjects.get(index).name;
}
 class Subject{
 int id;
string name;
}
```

I wish to use the List to bind my ArrayList, Can I set something like "display text field" for "name" field, and "value field" for my "id"? So that I can retrieve those values as needed.
The best dream is I can retrieve whole the selected "Subject" instead of a string field.
I seen the list only have getSelectedValue, and if I want to display the subject in the List, I must set getValueAt() in model to return the "name", and getSelectedValue() return the selected "name" too :( If I change getElementAt() in model class to return "Subject", the list will display @object.abxdef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override `toString()` of `Subject`, and return what ever you want to be displayed in the list. Then add all your `Subject` instances to the list. No need for a custom `ListModel`. Just use a [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). When you get the selected `Subject` just use one of it's getters to the field you want.

Also no need to store your object in two locations, (i.e. the ListModel *and* the ArrayList) just add everything to the model.

```
class Subject {
   private int id;
   private String name;

   public Subject(int id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getId() { return id; }
   public String getName() { return name; }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return name;
   }
}

DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement(new Subject(1, "Math"));
Subject subject = (Subject)model.getElementAt(0);
System.out.println(subject);
// result -> Math
```